# Show that $2x+4y=3$ and $x+2y=4$ are consistent over $GF(5)$ and inconsistent over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

> Show that the two equations
>   $$2x+4y=3$$
>   $$x+2y=4$$
>   are consistent over $GF_5$ but inconsistent over $\mathbb{R}$.

For $\mathbb{R}$, I can see that $\begin{pmatrix}2x+4y\\2x+4y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\8\end{pmatrix}$ has no solution.
Also, for $GF_5$, I can solve for each value (since the finite set has very few elements) and verify that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\end{pmatrix}$ are the only solutions to the system of equations.
Also, obviously it is enough to find even $1$ solution to the system in $GF_5$ to prove its consistency.

> Is there a formal proof for the above? My method seems to involve "verification" instead of a "proof", is it enough anyway?

Comment: You have shown what needed to be shown, what else would you do?

Comment: @Math1000 I meant is there a general proof? I was able to do this because $GF_5$ has few elements.

Comment: @Math1000 Oh, I just realized- 1 solution is enough. Also $\mathbb{R}$ case, is that enough to conclude what I want to?

Comment: What is $GF_5$ please?

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc I think $GF$ stands for Galois Field, but I only have a vv basic idea of $GF(n)-\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$

Comment: *$GF(n)=\{0,1,2,..,n-1\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, checking all possible solution *is* a valid proof.

Second, you could also have noticed that in $GF(5)$, $2x+4y=3$ and $2x+4y=8$ are the same equation since $3=8$ in characteristic five.

Comment: Got it!. In case $GF(n)$ has way more elements than I can verify for, it's enough to show consistency using 1 solution, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is.